# Which programming language has the least amount of syntax?

Tags: programming-languages, syntax

Which programming language has the least amount of syntax? How can I calculate how many syntax a programming language has?

Thanks.

Comment: To calculate how "many" syntax a programming language has, you may look at a language's grammar. The more grammar, the more syntax it has.

Comment: I think he means which language provides the fewest grammatical constructs to create code.

Comment: This is a good question, actually: 15%-20% of the population are dyslectic, this way or another; In addition, the less grammer a language have, the faster and a more readable code you produce, making it easy to maintain.

Comment: This question on programmers.SE, [Does syntax really matter in a programming language?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/30135/does-syntax-really-matter-in-a-programming-language), should be prerequisite reading for this question.

Answer (score 20):

Does [Brainfuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) count?

Oh wait...you meant a [useful](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html) language.

Comment: hahah, i was just about to post that.

Comment: I think Ook! has less syntax. =) http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/ook.html

Comment: Both Ook! and Brainfuck have 8 productions, so have the same amount of syntax. Ook! uses multi-token productions, so arguably has more complicated syntax.

Comment: Brainfuck is useful. How many rep point did we get just using it in an anwser ?

Comment: @sam: Ruby is indeed a wonderful language.

Comment: Flipjump might also be a valid answer (1 opcode): https://github.com/tomhea/flip-jump

Answer (score 10):

LISP-derived, Forth-derived and Smalltalk-derived (IO?) languages probably have the least syntax, in that order.

And you can't measure it, because it's not technical, it's social.

Comment: Forth has very little syntax, though variants build on it. Postscript (and by extension PDF) is a similar model to Forth, but with a lot more syntax.

Comment: Well, syntax is what you accumulate over time.

Comment: You certainly can measure syntax. The problem is that there are multiple competing measurements. The decision on which measurements count is the part that's social.

Comment: @alamar: *"syntax is what you accumulate over time"* - how can that be true with a constructed language? Surely the syntax (at least for the purpose of this question) is the set of symbols required to express an arbitrary statement? That's definitely measurable.

Comment: @naught101 users keep asking for new syntax and removing old syntax from language is problematic, hence accumulation (see Java for example)

Due to TIMTOWTDI reasoning about exact set required to express a statement is problematic.

Answer (score 8):

Programming languages that are implemented very close to some simple [computational model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language_theory) are likely to have very little syntax.

- Assembly languages, ie the [x86
  assembly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language#Syntax), based on [Turing
  machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine) model.
- Lisp and Lisp derived languages that are based on
  [Lambda calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus).

Comment: Last time I checked, my Intel computer didn't have a tape inside. x86 is register based.

Comment: IP register is the HEAD and memory is the TAPE.

Comment: The Turing machine has very few instructions with operate on the tape, which is a single stream of data and instructions with O(N) access. x86 is CISC device, and most read/writes operate on random access memory, not on the instruction stream. If anything it's based on Von-Neumann with separation of instruction and data - later variants have support to prevent you executing read/write memory.

Answer (score 5):

A Hello World in [Brainfuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck)

```
++++++++++[>+++++++>++++++++++>+++>+<<<<-]>++.>+.+++++++..+++.>++.<<+++++++++++++++.>.+++.------.--------.>+.>.
```

Comment: most programming languages use less code to print hello world. I don't see the point of this example.

Answer (score 5):

If I guess your purpose correctly, Python has no more or less "syntax" than any other language, but it has less "strange funny symbols" than any other language I know.
And it uses simplified, mostly plain English syntax.

If you're looking for a serious language in which it'd be easy to read and write, but still be prouctive, go for Python.

Or visual basic, which is becoming more and more bloated over the years, and it has syntax incompatibility issues with earlier versions - so I can't recommend VB.

Answer (score 1):

Most modern languages have relatively few keywords and operators. They usually have some way of indicating a logic block. The problem is that fewer keywords and operators don't usually mean easier to read and understand code - just look at BrainFuck - 4 operators, no keywords and pretty useless.

More 'natural' languages are more verbose and have a lot of syntax, but can be easier for a beginner.

Java, C#, Javascript and loads more languages share the same basic syntax. They all have their own extra keywords and operators, but if you're going to learn one basic syntax their's is where to start - if you can code in one you can read the others.

Comment: what about C++ is it share the same syntax with Java, C#, Javascript?

Comment: @zuizui C++ and C are similar in lots of syntactic ways, but so fundamentally different in terms of what they actually do it's probably worse. C# and Javascript are both kind of based on Java, though not directly, and all 3 are managed (though JS is dynamic rather than static types). Learning C won't help you with JS and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, I tried :

- Assembly;
- C/C++;
- Java;
- C#;
- PHP;
- Java;
- Python;
- Ruby;
- Bash;
- Perl.

Excepting bash, wich I do not even thing about when it comes to programming more that scripting, Perl has the shortest syntax, but it's one of the slowest to read.

Assembly, C/C++, and Java are really Verbose. C# and PHP less, but still. And you are stuck with .Net or with a language with no naming convention.

The best balance between being concise, powerful and readable are Ruby and Python.

I am a Python lover myself, and I'm use to the syntax so I'll go for it. I don't like the way Ruby ends blocks using keywords.

Answer (score 1):

I've a supposition that the relative complexity of a language is a function of the number of items a programmer has to know or remember to successfully get a module to compiile without errors. There are other things to enumerate in addition to keywords, like special symbols. Perhaps listing those symbols and delimiters would be useful as well. If a symbol is used for two different things it would be counted twice. For instance, in Smalltalk a period (.) is used to address a class explicitly through its namespace and to terminate a statement.

Language    Keywords
68000 Assembler >106
8088 Assembler  106
Ada 84
Java 1.1    64
Ruby    56
PHP 52  74 including special $variables
C++ 48
Ruby    38
C   28
Python  28
Smalltalk   6

Answer (score 0):

It rather depends on your definition of syntax. For example, [Subtext](http://subtextual.org/) no textual syntax, but quite a lot of visual syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about "least" amount of syntax, but if you mean succinct/lightweight, then undoubtedly the [K language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_(programming_language)) has to be a strong competitor.

Answer (score 0):

The parsing of [Jot](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Jot) can be done using only 5 characters: the `[01]*` regex is a full description of all and only legal programs.

Answer (score 0):

the compute programming language has no syntax. At all. http://esolangs.org/wiki/Compute
I must point out however that it cant actually do math.